# Visual Studio 2010 Express multi-language solutions

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-express

I am working on a C# project, which needs a VB.NET Class library.
I have added the DLL reference of VB.NET Project into C# project.
This works fine, but sometimes I need to debug the VB.NET project or pause the project and check the variable values of my VB.NET Project.

Is it possible in Visual Studio 2010 **Express** Edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is to keep two VisualStudio express open at the same time. One with the C# solution and the other one with the VB solution.

Also you make sure the VB project compiles where the c# finds its references (or reference the library from the Debug/Release folder)

At this point you can edit both the projects at the same time (it's tricky but it should work).

Problem is you do not have the "Attach to Process" feature of Visual Studio which would allow you to simply debug in one or another depending on the circumstances.

Maybe, you can follow these links to obtain what you want: 
http://stewartr.blogspot.com/2006/09/debugging-nunit-in-visual-studio.html

http://www2.wealth-lab.com/Wiki/kbDebugExpress.ashx

In the link, it shows how Nunit is attached to the debugger.

Hope it helps

Comment: So, how can I check variable values of class library (VB.NET) project at runtime? (when main (C#) project is running and it calls a function of class library (VB.NET))

Comment: Can I do that? (I have explained my request in my previous comment)

Comment: You can use that strategy to attach an external process, in your case you can attach your compiled executable.

Comment: Thanks for update. but I can't understand how these can help my problem. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Basically if your application is called ABC.Exe you substitute `<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>C:\Program Files\NUnit-Net-2.0 2.2.8\bin\nunit-gui.exe</StartProgram>` with `<StartAction>Program</StartAction>
<StartProgram>Abc.Exe</StartProgram>` in your VB express. This way you shoulld be able to debug the vb dlls.

Comment: My application calls a function from a DLL file, and I want to trace the code of that DLL file.

Comment: I believe so, not as smoothly as you would have with Visual Studio though ;)

Comment: Will attaching dll to debugger allows me to do that?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible to do with Visual Studio Express.  The Express SKU's only support a single language at a time.